# Remove duplicates from Node array properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a property `A` on my nodes that holds an array of string values:

`n.A=["ABC","XYZ","123","ABC"]`

During merges I frequently will write code similar to `n.A = n.A + "New Value"`.  The problem I've been running into is that I end up with duplicate values in my arrays; not insurmountable but I'd like to avoid it.

- How can I write a cypher query that will remove all duplicate values from the array `A`? Some duplicates have already been inserted at this point, and I'd like to clean them up.
- When adding new values to existing arrays how can I make sure I only save a copy of the array with distinct values? (may end up being the exact same logic as used to solve my first question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query to add a non-duplicate value can be done efficiently (in this example, I assume that the `id` and `newValue` parameters are provided):

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n {id: {id}})
WHERE NONE(x IN n.A WHERE x = {newValue})
SET n.A = n.A + {newValue};
```

This query does not create a temporary array, and will only alter the `n.A` array if it does not already contain the {newValue} string.

[EDITED]

If you want to (a) create the `n` node if it does not already exist, and (b) append `{newValue}` to `n.A` only if `{newValue}` is not already in `n.A`, this should work:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n { id: {id} })
FOREACH (x IN (
  CASE WHEN n IS NULL THEN [1] ELSE [] END ) | 
  CREATE ({ id: {id}, A: [{newValue}]}))
WITH n, CASE WHEN EXISTS(n.A) THEN n.A ELSE [] END AS nA
WHERE NONE (x IN nA WHERE x = {newValue})
SET n.A = nA + {newValue};
```

If the `OPTIONAL MATCH` fails, then the `FOREACH` clause will create a new node node (with the `{id}` and an array containing `{newValue}`), and the following `SET` clause will do nothing because `n` would be NULL.

If the `OPTIONAL MATCH` succeeds, then the `FOREACH` clause will do nothing, and the following `SET` clause will append `{newValue}` to `n.A` iff that value does not already exist in `n.A`. If the `SET` should be performed, but the existing node did not already have the `n.A` property, then the query would concatenate an empty array to `{newValue}` (thus generating an array containing just `{newValue}`) and set that as the `n.A` value.

Comment: How would I incorporate this into the `ON MATCH` portion of my `MERGE` statement?  Right now I have
`MERGE (n {id:{id}})
ON CREATE SET n.A= [{newValue}]
ON MATCH SET n.A= n.A + {newValue}`

I tried tacking on parts of your code after `ON MATCH` but Neo4j told me the only allowed item was `SET`.

Comment: See the addendum to my answer.

Comment: @cybersam just for copleteness, i'd remove foreach cycle and use `MERGE` instead of `OPTIONAL MATCH`, otherwise it will create a new node with only 1 newValue and you have to run again the query to update the node.

Answer (score 3):

Combined some of the information on [UNWIND](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-unwind.html) with other troubleshooting and came up with the following Cypher query for removing duplicates from existing array properties.

```
match (n)
unwind n.system as x
with distinct x, n
with collect(x) as set, n
set n.system = set
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you've cleaned up existing duplicates, you can use this when adding new values:

```
match (n)
set n.A = filter (x in n.A where x<>"newValue") + "newValue"
```